# Can hierarchyviewer be used with a real device other than the Nexus?

Tags: android, hierarchyviewer

I'd really like to use `hierarchyviewer` with my Samsung Galaxy S. Is there any way to turn it into a developer phone?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

RomainGuy is correct, but since he had developed the debug ViewServer you can use HierarchyViewer for your own application on ANY phone now. To do this simply add RomainGuy's `ViewServer` into your application.

https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer

From [ViewServer](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer/blob/master/viewserver/src/main/java/com/android/debug/hv/ViewServer.java) JavaDoc:

> This class can be used to enable the use of HierarchyViewer inside an
>   application. HierarchyViewer is an Android SDK tool that can be used 
>   to inspect and debug the user interface of running applications. For 
>   security reasons, HierarchyViewer does not work on production builds 
>   (for instance phones bought in store.) By using this class, you can 
>   make HierarchyViewer work on any device. You must be very careful 
>   however to only enable HierarchyViewer when debugging your 
>   application.
>
> To use this view server, your application must require the
>   `INTERNET` permission.

If you use Android Annotations library, it's even simpler - just annotate your activity with [`@HierarchyViewerSupport`](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/HierarchyViewerSupport) annotation.

Comment: When RomainGuy wrote his answer he hadn't developed debug ViewServer yet ;)

Comment: I want to run it on program that I didn't develop , how can I do that ?

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush if you don't have rooted device this is not possible. If your devices is rooted, there are several options available:  1) [Patch `WindowManagerService.isSystemSecure()`](http://blog.apkudo.com/2012/07/26/enabling-hierarchyviewer-on-rooted-android-devices/),  2) [patch `default.prop` file in `boot.img`](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Unpack,_Edit,_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images),  3) Install XPosed Framework, and [hook activity methods](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial) mentioned in `ViewServer` documentation

Answer (score 11):

HierarchyViewer works only on debug/engineering device.

Comment: how to convert my device (nexus6) to a debug/engineering one

Answer (score 2):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30169985/1066739) - on devices with Android 4.1+ the only thing you need is to set the environmental variable `ANDROID_HVPROTO=ddm`and restart adb server.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps given [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/setup.html)

Then restart the hierarchyviewer by going to:

- `/Library/Android/sdk/tools` on a Mac
- `C:\Program Files\Android\Sdk\tools` on Windows

and run `./hierarchyviewer`