# Android tool to show where a view is

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any android tool to inspect where views are in the layout of a live run? What I mean is when I'm running my app connected to the computer and debuggin with eclipse.

I have one fragment that I really don't know where has gone and I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: you can put breakpoints. may be you can figure your issue.

Comment: Heirarchy viewer in tools or on later ADT versions, in the DDMS perspective

Answer (score 2):

There are two very useful tools to debug the UI layout. First one is in eclipse `Dump view hierarchy of UI` and the second one available under the `Developer options` in the Android device itself (see the below screenshots)

[image: Dump view hierarchy of UI]
[image: Developer Options]

Answer (score 1):

Use heirarchy viewer on your emulator. It will show you view hierarchy and some view's parameters.

Heirarchy viewer work only on emulator. But you can add [such functionality to real device.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011008/can-hierarchyviewer-be-used-with-a-real-device-other-than-the-nexus)